# array of pointers arithmetic

Tags: c

I was experimenting with array of pointers address calculation arithmetic.I got confused with the output of the above code.Could anyone explain whats happening?

```
void foo()
{
    int i=10,k=3,l=20,m=30;
    int *ary[2];
    ary[0]=&i;
    int b=20;
    ary[1]=&k;

    printf("%d\n",ary[0][1]);
}
```

**Output is 3**

**Second program**

```
void foo()
{
    int i=10,k=3,l=20,m=30;
    int *ary[2];
    ary[0]=&i;
    int b=20;
    ary[1]=&b;

    printf("%d\n",ary[0][1]);
}
```

**Output is 20.**

How is address calculation done in these above codes?

Comment: What's the difference between those 2 programs?

Comment: What @Jon Lin said, and how are you calling `foo`? There's a chance for _undefined behavior_...

Comment: The difference is that `ari[1]` is assigned `&k` in the first program and `&b` in the second.

Comment: sorry....changed the code now...now it has no undefined behaviour..

Comment: Both programs print `10` on my mac.

Comment: Of course it has UB ... why would you say it doesn't?

Comment: @ObscureRobot That seems pretty unlikely. Perhaps your transcription was in error.

Comment: @JimBalter I agree, but I didn't type, I copied.

Comment: Well, I always knew a Mac was magical. :-)

Comment: I usually think of it as "special".

Comment: Of course, undefined behavior *is* undefined. I might run foo() in a loop all night and see if any gold coins come out of the superdrive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both code samples `ary[0]` is a pointer to a single integer. So when you do `array[0][1]` you're accessing that pointer out of bounds. So the behavior of both of your code samples is undefined.

The reason that you're getting the behavior you're seeing on your particular compiler is probably, that all the variables whose address you don't take are stored in registers and not in memory (or possibly they aren't stored at all because you never use them).

So in example 1 the only variables in memory are i and k. And in example 2 the only variables in memory are i and b. So in example 1 `k` is the variables that comes directly after `i` in memory and example 2 that variable is `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is

```
int *ary[]
```

and in function arguments, array decay to pointers. So you basically have

```
int** ary
```

You then set the pointer at index 0, *presumably* a valid index, to the value of a single variable.

```
ary[0]=&i;
```

Then your code prints

```
ary[0][1]
```

which is basically

```
( &i )[1]
```

triggering *undefined behavior*, hence whatever result you get is a valid result.

Comment: my speculation was about how compiler does this.shouldnt it give value of variable immediately next to it.why does it gives value of k first time and then value of b next.shouldnt it give same variable each time?

Comment: @vindhya: When you trigger _undefined behavior_, the compiler has free pass to do whatever it wants to do. It could just crash, it could just return some random value, it could just return the variable immediately next to it... It could even decide that under no _defined behavior_ will you call `foo`, and hence generate no code for it.